# Getting SelectedItem Issue on ComboBox - MVVM ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, observablecollection, selecteditem

Firstly, my apologies to any one who may feel like this is a very dumb question or a question that has already been answered. I'm very new to MVVM, XAML and having read everything on StackOverflow, I'm still failing to understand what I'm sure is a simple concept.

So I have a MVVM set up where an Observable Collection is put into a ComboBox. Here is the view.

```
public class AppSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public class Regions
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
        public string region { get; set; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Regions> _ItemsRegions = new ObservableCollection<Regions>
    {
        new Regions() { code = 0, region = "Metro : All Areas" },
        new Regions() { code = 25, region = "Metro : North of River"},
        new Regions() { code = 26, region = "Metro : South of River"},
        new Regions() { code = 27, region = "Metro : East/Hills"},
    };
    public ObservableCollection<Regions> Region
    {
        get { return this._ItemsRegions; }
    }

    private Regions _selectedRegion;
    public Regions SelectedRegion
    {
        get { return _selectedRegion; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedRegion)
            {
                _selectedRegion = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedRegion");
            }
        }
    }
```

And for reference, here is my ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox Name="Regions" ItemsSource="{Binding Region}" DisplayMemberPath="region" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRegion, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Now the good news is that I have the SelectedItem working and I'm able to with the MVVM obtain the values I need to make changes etc. which is great! That concept was a little difficult to grasp at first but once I had it, I knew what was going on. So I can save the data in any way at this point.... The eventual plan is to put it in roaming data. This is a Universal App.

So the problem is the user is finished with this page and navigates away from it . When he/she comes back to it the ComboBox is loaded with all the data (as expected) but the SelectedItem that I just saved is not. As in, the "IsSelected = True" item is null so it just says "choose an item".

What do I need to do in order to on page load, get the SelectedItem from save and set it to the ComboBox. I've been stupid and tried setting the Region.ComboBox.SelectedItem to a "string", but of course that defeats and destroys the whole MVVM purpose!

So, what do I need to do? I'm happy to be just pointed at some documentation for me to read.

**Update Edit**

So following advise from a user on here I took my get; set INotifyPropertyChanged logic and put it in a blank app. Just to see that I'm not doing anything stupid.

Unfortunately the blank app also has the same problem where navigation away from the page and back to it has none of my previously selected values... To illustrate this, here is a quick screenshot.

To navigate back, I'm using the hardware back button.

[image: Screenshot of what's happening]

I'm guessing that I'm just missing a piece of the puzzle to make this work. This whole MVVM XAML concept is new to me and while I'm learning a lot about it, I'm genuinely stuck on this!

Any takers? Tips? Ideas? Examples?

**Update 2**

Okay so following some more advise posted in the comments on this question, I went and added a debugger track on the Object ID for "this._selectedRegion".

The watch of the Object ID shows that the data is in fact set correctly when a user selects one of the items from the combobox. Great! But when the user navigates away from the page and comes back to it, it's set to null. Not Great!

With my bland/stupid face am I missing the point completely? Am I meant to be on "OnNavigatedTo" aka, fist load setting the SelectedItem for the combobox myself? As in the data is never saved on navigation away and coming back to it is setting is null is in fact expected in MVVM? Do I manipulate the "get" statement and specify the ObservableCollection Item it's meant to be? Crude way, but like

`_selectedRegion = something
 return _selectedRegion`

This sounds awfully crude to me and not what it should be, but maybe I'm just not appreciating the MVVM set up properly?

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: Are you sure you set `SelectedRegion` in your ViewModel to one of the items in `_ItemsRegions`by the time _the user comes back_?

Comment: Side-note: I think it should be `public class Region` (singular)

Comment: Hi @DrKoch. To answer your first comment, I'm pretty sure I'm able to get the values of _ItemRegion. For example `var mes = new MessageDialog(_selectedRegion.code.ToString()); mes.ShowAysnc()` makes the value appear in the message box.

For the side-note. This is no Public class Region? Should I be doubling up and copying Regions?

Comment: No, I just found your use of singular/plural forms confusing: The class should be "MyRegion" the list "MyRegions". I said: **set** `SelectedItem`

Comment: @DrKoch, apologies about the singular/plural forms. This was just a rush job and I did get them mixed around a bit from examples on the internet.  Can you explain a bit more on the `Set SelectedItem`. Am I missing a bit of code logic here?

Comment: Why is this `AppSettings`? Looks very strange to me...

Comment: @DrKoch Again apologies for the horrible naming. The AppSettings name can be changed though I believe this wont fix my issue.

Comment: My advice: Make a (very) small project (with clean naming) and try to reproduce it there.

Comment: @DrKoch. Did this - Same result. I think I'm just not understanding the concept.

Comment: Are you sure you look at the **same page** (i.e. the same viewModel instance) the second time? (Work with object ID in the debugger)

Comment: Sorry @DrKoch but I don't know how you properly use the debugger. Any tips?

Comment: Well, this is beyond a simple comment. My urgent advice: Lear to use the debugger! In this case also focus on Object-Id

Answer (score 0):

For a `ComboBox` in WPF it is very important to set `SelectedItem` to one of the items in `ItemsSource`.

Make sure that `SelectedItem` has the correct value (or is set) *when he/she comes back*.

---

**Edit**

Your binding

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRegion, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

will call the getter of `SelectedRegion` when the control is built. It will call the setter when the value in the ComboBox changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but for some clarification how can I check this? The SelectedItem from what I can see is from the databind of itemsource? As in the values match one of the options!

Comment: set breakpoints in the getter and setter of `SelectedRegion`. observe what happens when user _navigates away_ and _comes back_

Comment: They're firing as expected/ or I'm not seeing an issue with it. The navigation to the page "gets" and selecting from the list "sets" using appropriate breakpoints.

Is there a way to check the data on get? See what it's trying to set the selecteditem as?

Comment: With your binding in place the value of the property should always be the visible value in the combobox (as long as ItemsSource is correct)

Comment: But it's not? Thanks for the edit, this is what I understood as it as well but the SelectedItem is not set upon return to the page. Many more suggestions? Could it be an issue that the on build calling is wiping the value out and reloading it and in between that time the SelectedItem is trying to set? 

I'm stuck on this one as it seems that no one else on StackOverflow has this issue.